# how to return a variable from another window in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have one main window and one dialog in PYQT. I receive the input from user in main window and then open the dialog window and pass the input to this window.

in dialog window again I receive another input and add this new input with the other input which I passed form main window.

[image]

```
class MainWindow (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window=Ui_MainWindow() 
        self.window.setupUi(self)   

     def open_qdialog_window(self):
        
        self.dialog_window = Qdialog(self.window.lineedit1.currentText())

        self.dialog_window .show()

class Qdialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,DS_parameter):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.DS_parameters=DS_parameters
        #UI file of oscilloscope
    
        self.window=Ui_Qdialog()
        self.window.setupUi(self)
        self.UI()
    
    def summation(self):
        self.DS_parameters=self.DS_parameters+self.window.lineedit2.currentText()
```

Now the question is how I can return self.DS_parameters to the main window and update editline1 with this new value?

Answer (score 1):

To me, it is difficult to provide you with specific (probably more helpful) feedback on your code, since the part you shared is incomplete. However, I hope that my rather general answer is somewhat useful.

In Qt, [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) are used to establish connections between GUI elements. The basic idea is that an event triggers the execution of a function. For instance, whenever a button is pressed, some text gets updated. Below you find a working example illustrating how to return the sum to the main window and update the corresponding line.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QDialog,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QLabel,
    QPushButton
    )


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_input = QLineEdit()
        self.populate()
        self.show()

    def populate(self):
        widgets = [QLabel("Insert a number"), self.user_input]
        centralWidget = self.group_widgets(widgets)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

    def group_widgets(self, widgets):
        parentWidget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        for widget in widgets: layout.addWidget(widget)
        parentWidget.setLayout(layout)
        return parentWidget

    def when_input(self, function):
        self.user_input.textChanged.connect(function)

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_input = QLineEdit()
        self.admin_input = QLineEdit("0")
        self.button = QPushButton("add")
        self.relay_sum = None  # function to relay result of addition
        self.populate()
        self.show()

    def populate(self):
        widgets = self.get_widgets()
        layout = self.get_layout(widgets)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def get_widgets(self):
        widgets = [
            QLabel("Inserted number"),
            self.user_input,
            QLabel("Insert the second number"),
            self.admin_input,
            self.button
            ]
        return widgets

    def get_layout(self, widgets):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        for widget in widgets: layout.addWidget(widget)
        return layout

    def when_buttonReleased(self, function):
        self.relay_sum = function
        self.button.released.connect(self.process_input)

    def process_input(self):
        user_number = float(self.user_input.text())
        admin_number = float(self.admin_input.text())
        result = "%.2f" %(user_number + admin_number)
        self.relay_sum(result)

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    dialog = Dialog()
    mainWindow.when_input(lambda text: dialog.user_input.setText(text))
    dialog.when_buttonReleased(lambda text: mainWindow.user_input.setText(text))
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you have noticed, I allowed myself to change variable names you proposed. In the example, two windows are created and two connections are established:

[1. connection] Whenever the text of the main window is changed (*MainWindow.user_input.textChanged*), the new text is set as the content of the corresponding line in the dialog window (*Dialog.user_input.setText*).

[2. connection] Whenever the button in the dialog window is released (*Dialog.button.released*), the values in the dialog window are summed and the result is set as text of the main window (*MainWindow.user_input.setText*).